# How can firefox/xorg/??? preserve something rendered on my screen weeks ago?

Tags: linux, firefox, arch-linux, xorg, i3

Something rather strange happened, I opened my laptop (it was sleeping) and I saw my screen render the firefox browser with some old tabs, including one with zoom open and an image of me & my friend having a call (which happened cca 10 days ago)

This is not the first time I've seen this sort of anomaly happen but, to be honest, I never thought much about it.

The screen went back to "normal" within seconds.

This seems odd because, if it was some sort of firefox caching error, it would presumably not have cached an exact screencap of the call. If it was related to X-server or some other part of the rendering pipeline I can't imagine why/where this image would have been cached.

I'm using endeavorOS, which is mainly a skin/easy-install on top of arch,  with the i3 wm.

I don't think it's possible to "solve" this per se since the state needed to debug it is gone, but, I'm curious, as to what are potential paths that could even cause this behavior?

It's not an issue with my computer but it does strike burning curiosity in my heart.

Comment: Which GPU driver are you using? I've seen such bugs occur in the past, something to do with the driver somehow telling the GPU to draw a buffer from the wrong part of VRAM that happened to correspond to an old buffer. (RAM, just like HDDs, doesn't purge "unused" data – what was written to RAM stays in RAM until overwritten by something new. I.e. it's the opposite of deliberate caching.)